# How to solve "$result->property" when returning nothing in PHP

Tags: php

### Case

So once I learned PHP the **non ObjectOriented** way I decided to move to it.

While doing a simple query, I get the **"rows"** the query returns but trying **to access its fields** (columns) just seems not to work.

To be clearer, I have this **PHP** code, where I show the results into a table:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
    include 'connectDB.php';

    $connection = openConnection();

    //Query
    $query = "SELECT
                field1,
                field2
              FROM table";

//Check there are results
if($result = $connection->query($query)) {

       //get data
   while($object = $result->fetch_object()) {
   ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php $object->field1 ?></td>
        <td><?php $object->field2 ?></td>
      </tr>

       <?php
   }

     closeConnection($connection);

  } else {
       echo '<tr><td>No info found.</td></tr>';
  }
?>
```

Where **openConnection()** and **closeConnection()** are functions from the "connectDB.php" file. Those are ok, but in case it is relevant:

```
function openConnection() {
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "user1";
    $dbpass = "1234";
    $db = "myDatabase";
    $connection = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db) or die(" Error while connecting: %s\n". $connection->error);

    return $connection;
}

function closeConnection($connection) {
    $connection -> close();
}
```

### What I tried

I've already tried the following:

```
$object = mysqli_fetch_object($result)
$object = $result->fetch_result("newClass") // and created a new class
```

And down in selecting the fields:

```
$object->returnData() //where this is a function that literally does return $this->field1
```

Also checked a lot of **PHP** codes where it supposedly worked and was the same as the first code block mentioned above.

### Result:

What I get as result is 9 rows, which is what the query should return, but trying to access with `<?php $object->field1 ?>` just leaves a blank space.

If I open the *Web Inspector*, there's actually nothing inside the `<td>`.

[image: Screenshot]

**Extra:** I'm using XAMPP on its lastest version 7.3.4 and Bootstrap 4.

**Extra 2:** the SQL query works separately.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not echoing the value out. Try this:

```
<tr>
    <td><?= $object->field1 ?></td>
    <td><?= $object->field2 ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! So `<?=` seems to `echo` what follows, meaning that a simple `echo` would solve it?

Comment: Yes, `<?= $var ?>` is the short tag for `<?php echo $var ?>`